# Any software to prevent an executable from closing others executables?

Tags: windows, sandbox

I'm in search of a windows application that would prevent another application to close all instances of a third application (steam/discord/epic games) : It automatically closes the application I ask it to launch before switching between accounts, and I would like to find something that would isolate it enough to make it unable to kill the other application without launching the whole application in a sandbox or anything

It's a software that allows for fast switching between accounts, but it automatically kills any application I start from it ; thus, I can only have one instance of each application I choose to start.
I cannot launch two instances of epic games from it, nor steam or discord. Launching from sandboxie/sandboxie-plus or even Avast sandbox doesn't resolve anything, as it starts itself either outside these or just doesn't start since it detects itself being launched

Any way to prevent it of doing so, thus allowing me to finally have multiple discord/steam/epics going on ? Thanks :)